# bash shell check each file for empty size

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Need to start creating scripts in bash, which I never had to before, so forgive if I'm ignorant to things thet may be obvious to some of you.

using bash script (.sh) I need to get a bunch of files that match a certain naming pattern and figure out if they are empty.

I know that I can check if the file is empty by using the `-s FILE` code, but how do I loop thorugh files in directory and check this.

For example, I need to get all files in the directory that match pattern `*Export*UK*.csv` and check if each file is empty of not, so in pseudocode

```
if [[ -s FILE_NAME_HERE ]]
then
    # file is not empty, do this
else
    # file is empty, do that instead
fi
```

Comment: [check this out](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) .. it would be something like `for f in *Export*UK*.csv; do if..fi done`

Comment: Side note: almost any modern system nowadays supports more than just "bash". So, if you are not too eager about learning bash ... it might feel better for you to use a language such as python. Which allows for a very much different programming experience.

Comment: @GhostCat - I agree. However I'm not the owner of the system. I have to work with what I was given, unfortunately.

Comment: Then write a bash script that calls a python script ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `test -s $file` (aka `[ -s $file ]`) which returns "true if file exists and has a size greater than zero". To iterate through files, you need something like:

```
for file in /your/base/directory/*Export*UK*.csv; do
    if [ -s "$file" ]; then
        # non-empty
    else
        # empty
    fi
done
```

You can replace the absolute path with just `for file in *Export*UK*.csv` if those files are in the current dir.

Answer (score 1):

Try `find`-

```
find ~/location -print0 -type f -name "*Export*UK*.csv" -empty | xargs -0 **do this**
find ~/location -print0 -type f -name "*Export*UK*.csv" -not -empty | xargs -0 **do that instead**
```

Of course the looping with the `if` is better but this is another way.

Comment: Hint: add -type f ... no need to *find* anything else but files!

Comment: @GhostCat Yup, that's much more specific. Added the path to search as well. Thanks.

Comment: Waiting for someone to complain that this won't work with filenames that have spaces in them (use `-print0` with `find` and `-0` with `xargs`)

Comment: @SeanBright, There you go, much more robust now, thanks!